# WCF in ASP.NET compatibility mode and charset encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, character-encoding

I am working on fairly large web application that has a RESTful service built on WCF using`WebServiceHostFactory`. The REST service encodes the response according to request's preferences (AcceptCharset http header) and returns it as a MemoryStream. MemoryStream should bypass WCF serialization as far as I know. Both web application and service are hosted in IIS.

REST service used to work in side-by-side mode, but now we want to add couple more WCF services for AJAX layer using configuration very similar to`WebScriptServiceHostFactory`and those pretty much require the service hosting environment to be switched to asp.net compatibility mode to access http context for authentication and stuff like that. So I added AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute with parameter`AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed`to the REST service class and following line to the web.config.

`<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />`

Everything works quite fine and requests asking for utf-8 encoded message get propertly encoded response, but all other charset types I tried end up in response with broken special characters (eg. ščřžýáíé). When I turn the asp.net compatibility mode back off on the application many other character encodings can be processed correctly (eg. windows-1250, iso-8859-2, utf-16).

I think it has something to do with requests to WCF service being processed by asp.net http pipeline. Is there a way to stop it from interferring with my response encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record: in the end we found there was a bug in our custom output filter, it had UTF-8 hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that when you activate the *aspNetCompatibilityEnabled*, the *requestEncoding* and *responseEncoding* of the *globalization* element in your web.config or machine.config interferes with your WCF encodings.

I don't know if the solution must be programmatic :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2008/02/26/using-call-context-initializers-for-culture.aspx

Comment: So in aspNetCompatibility mode I need to create custom endpoint behaviour class with a piece of code that will set encoding. While in side-by-side mode none of this is required. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly, but that's only my opinion.

I would be interested if you find a more flexible solution based on configuration/attributes.